# How to redirect domain to ip using htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using a AJAX code for a HTTPS call. when I am using direct ip, it only works for ip, but if I use domain name it is not working.
 If I change it to domain name then it works only for domain name.

I want to get it work both for ip and domain. How can I do this?

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url : "https://banglamail.test.com:8080/test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : 'username='+user_name+'&password='+password,
```

then it's only working for https://banglamail.test.com:8080/test.php,
but if I put ip instead https://192.168.21.30:8080/test.php then it's not working.

Can you please suggest me how can I put rule in .htaccess file?

Comment: Check weather you redirecting in the webserver both to the same place. Are you able to directly locate the IP in browser

Comment: no i only access one at a time. if i put ip then access ip but ip i put domain name then i access only using domain name

Comment: Guessing: does you have valid https ssl?

Comment: yes i have valid ssl. by the it;s not ssl issue. i am asking about redirect rule of ip to domain name